# I can't load a .joblib file to my views.py on my django project

Tags: python, django, joblib

My .joblib file is in the same directory as views.py literally next to each other but views.py cannot load it and once I runserver FileNotFoundError is thrown.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import joblib

@csrf_exempt
def test(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
    
        age = int(response.POST['age'])
        gender_str = str(response.POST['gender'])
        
        if gender_str == 'Male':
            gender_value = 1
        else:
            gender_value = 0
        
        openness = int(response.POST['openness'])
        neuroticism = int(response.POST['neuroticism'])
        conscientiousness = int(response.POST['conscientiousness'])
        agreeableness = int(response.POST['agreeableness'])
        extraversion = int(response.POST['extraversion'])

        personality_values_1 = [[gender_value, age, openness, neuroticism, conscientiousness, agreeableness, extraversion]]
        theModel = joblib.load('PersonalityTestLogisticRegression.joblib')
        prediction = theModel.predict(personality_values_1)
        prediction_value = prediction[0]
        
    return render(response, "main/Review_Test.html", {'prediction':prediction_value})
```

I tried everything I can and I'm new to django. Pulling my hair rn.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a relative import.

Change to:

```
from . import joblib
```

Comment: No luck buddy :(

Comment: Maybe full path from project directory would work, like `import your_app.joblib`, since when you make a manage.py runserver command, python interpreter serches imports on manage.py file level.

Answer (score 0):

try using the folder name in which the joblib file and views file are ex:
if your joblib file and view file are in a folder name my_app then use

```
theModel = joblib.load('my_app/PersonalityTestLogisticRegression.joblib')
```

where my_app is folder name in which your joblib file and views.py are present

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).